# Shell script issues - pipe to variable, compare float

Tags: python, shell

I'm fairly new to shell scripting but I thought this was going to be easy - I was wrong :/

I'm using an accelerometer to grab a value but when I try to send the value returned from a python script I can't get it into a variable.

```
python example3.py > $gvalue
```

example3.py just returns the value of one of the y coordinate as a float and I know it works when I call it from the command line.

I then want to take the value and compare it to -0.20 in an if statement but this isn't working either:

```
if [ $gvalue < -0.19 ]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to put the output of a command into a variable is:

```
gvalue=$(python example3.py)
```

`>` is for redirecting output to a file -- in your case, it will try to use the value of `$gvalue` as the name of the file to redirect to.

Most shells don't support floating point arithmetic or comparison, so you're not going to be able to do that comparison in the script. Perhaps you could change your Python script to take the value that it should compare against, and then print a `true` or `false` result.